# Core dump when I want to get the init stack infomation

Tags: c, linux, stack, coredump

I write a little test to try to print init stack of a program, here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <elf.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int *p = (int*)argv;
    int i;
    Elf32_auxv_t* aux;
    printf("Argument count: %d\n", *(p - 1));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < *(p - 1); ++i)
    {
        printf("Argument %d : %s\n", i, *(p + i));
    }
    
    p+=i;    
    p++;
    printf("Enviroment\n");
    
    while (*p)
    {
        printf("%s\n", *p);
        p++;
    }
    
    p++;
    
    printf("Auxiliary Vector\n");
    aux = (Elf32_auxv_t*)p;
    while (aux->a_type != AT_NULL)
    {
        printf("Type: %02d Value: %x\n", aux->a_type, aux->a_un.a_val);
        aux++;
    }
    
    return 0;

}
```

The thing I want to see is to print the environment pointer and AT_PHDR, AT_PHENT, AT_PHNUM, AT_ENTRY and AT_NULL. But the result shows here is a core dump

```
Argument count: 0
Enviroment
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What's wrong with the program? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Note that the _third_ argument to `main` isn't discussed much (a pointer to the environment): `int main(int argc,char **argv,char **envp)` If you're on certain arches (e.g. `x86_64`), `argc`, `argv`, and `envp` are _not_ on the stack. They are in registers: (`%edi`, `%rsi`, `%rdx`, respectively). If you want to see/dump the initial _stack_, you want `__builtin_frame_address(0)` and do (e.g.): `char **vp = __builtin_frame_address(0); for (int idx = 0;  idx < 32;  ++idx, ++vp) printf("%d: %p %p\n",idx,vp,*vp);`

Comment: @Craig Estey Thanks for your reply. So this program may only work in 32bit system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is prefaced by my top comment.

> Thanks for your reply. So this program may only work in 32bit system.

You *could* [sort of] use (e.g.):

```
void *vp = &argc;
```

This would *not* be the real frame for 64 bit. The compiler would store `argc` into a dummy area in the stack frame of `main` and point to that. It's similar but not quite the same as it would be in 32 bits.

But ... Your pointer arithmetic is a bit fragile (e.g.):

```
printf("Argument count: %d\n", *(p - 1));
```

won't work too well.

Here's some code I wrote to do [essentially] what you were doing, but in a clean(er) way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int glob_argc;
char **glob_argv;
char **glob_envp;
void *glob_frame;

void
showframe(void)
{
    char **vp = glob_frame;

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < 32;  ++idx, ++vp)
        printf("%d: %p %p\n",idx,vp,*vp);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv,char **envp)
{

    glob_argc = argc;
    glob_argv = argv;
    glob_envp = envp;

    glob_frame = __builtin_frame_address(0);
    printf("glob_frame=%p\n",glob_frame);

    printf("glob_argc=%d\n",glob_argc);
    printf("glob_argv=%p\n",glob_argv);
    printf("glob_envp=%p\n",glob_envp);
    showframe();

    return 0;
}
```